# Вопрос по параллельной программе

Tags: c++, распараллеливание

Написал параллельную программу на с++ с использованием mpi. Но толком не понял почему она быстрее, чем с использованием open mp. Есть варианты почему? Связано ли это с тем, что программу с open mp я тестировал на реальной windows, а программу с mpi на виртуальном ubuntu?

Comment: И это тоже может играть роль. Но основной вопрос - как именно выполнено распараллеливание. При неправильном распараллеливании можно и затормозить выполнение...

Comment: @Harry, есть рекурсивный алгоритм [Штрассена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC), который выполняется в 7 потоков с помощью open mp и в 8 процессов с помощью mpi. Не знаю стоит ли выкладывать код того и другого, потому что при виде страшного кода никто не отвечает обычно.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо